# GoLang consume json message from kafka

Tags: json, go, apache-kafka

I am running kafka localy with the following command :

`./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testTop`

after that, I send this message to the consumer in the command line:

```
{
   "field1":"value1",
   "keys":{
      "fieldId":"fd",
      "fieldId2":"fd2",
      "personId":"pr1",
      "rand":"lkfdnvlkdsjf"
   }
}
```

the message is consumed by golang client and the code unmarhsales it by struct:

```
type Message struct {
    field1 string          `json:"field1"`
    keys  struct {
        fieldId string `json:"fieldId"`
        fieldId2  string `json:"fieldId2"`
        personId  string `json:"personId"`
        rand     string `json:"rand"`
    } `json:"keys"`
}
```

if I unmarshal using interface:

```golang
   var m map[string]interface{} 
     json.Unmarshal(msg.Value, &m)
```

it returns :

```golang
     map[field1:value1 keys:map[fieldId:fd fieldId2:fd2 personId:pr1 rand:lkfdnvlkdsjf]]
```

but if I use unmarshaling with a struct pointer:

```golang
m := Message{}  
json.Unmarshal(msg.Value, &m)
```

the output is not full like this:

```golang
    {value1 {   }}
```

is there a way to unmarshal the message correctly with struct pointer?

Comment: The field of the struct should be uppercase, so use `Field1` instead of `field1`

Comment: `The json package only accesses the exported fields of struct types (those that begin with an uppercase letter). Therefore only the the exported fields of a struct will be present in the JSON output.` https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Comment: thanks , I changed fields names to uppercase. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by the steps:

1. Initial a struct like you: Message {}
2. Convert the body from Message to []byte using JSON at Kafka Producer:

```golang
...

var ev *Message

payload, err := json.Marshal(ev)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = op.Producer.Produce(&kafka.Message{
    TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &op.Topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
    Value:          payload,
},
    op.DeliveryCh,
)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
} 
...
```

3. Convert []byte to JSON using JSON lib in Kafka Consumer:

```golang
...

ev := consumer.Poll(100)
switch e := ev.(type) {
case *kafka.Message:
    /** We are going to detect interface and convert to Obj json
    Therefore, action event will run
    */
    var obj = &Message{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(e.Value, obj)
    if err != nil {
        // panic(err)
    }
...
```